# How to apply conditional function in data frame updating consecutive columns in R

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, dplyr, conditional-statements

Consider following data frame, with x being increasing numbers (don't have to be integers) and y varying values:

```
x | y | d.x | d.y | abs(d.y)/d.x
---------------------------------
1 | 5 |  1  |   5 | 5
2 | 9 |  1  |   4 | 4
3 | 1 |  1  |  -8 | 8
4 | 7 |  1  |   6 | 6
5 | 5 |  1  |  -2 | 2
6 | 1 |  1  |  -4 | 4
7 | 3 |  1  |   2 | 2
8 | 9 |  1  |   6 | 6
```

Here, `d.x` and `d.y` represent the differenced values. I want to identify the first value of `abs(d.y)/d.x` that is above a certain threshold (e.g. >5). This would be at `x = 3`. From the next row I want to reset `abs(d.y)/d.x` so that it skips `x = 3`, i.e.:

```
x | y | d.x | d.y | abs(d.y)/d.x
---------------------------------
1 | 5 |  1  |   5 | 5
2 | 9 |  1  |   4 | 4
4 | 7 |  2  |  -2 | 1
5 | 5 |  1  |  -2 | 2
6 | 1 |  1  |  -4 | 4
7 | 3 |  1  |   2 | 2
8 | 9 |  1  |   6 | 6
```

Now `x=8` would be identified as being above the treshold. This problem can easily be implemented in case there are no consecutive `abs(d.y)/d.x` that overlap at some point. The implementation can for example be done with a `while` loop, but I'm certain that someone knows how to do this with e.g. `ave, dplyr`,etc. I'm doing this with a hundreds of vector with a size of more than 10^6 entries, thus speed is of importance.

The values above the threshold do not have to be removed, I simply want to end up with a vector that contains the index positions (i.e. 3,8, etc.).

Thanks in advance.

My MWE with some random numbers.

```
# Random initialization 
set.seed(1)
y <- randi(20,20000,1)
x <- 1:length(x)
d.x <- diff(x)
d.y <- diff(y)
dy_dx <- abs(d.y)/d.x
idx <- array(0,length(d.y)) # stores if dy_dx above threshold
# Randomly chosen threshold
threshold <- 14

while(1==1){
# Identify values above threshold
    idx.new <- match(TRUE, dy_dx > threshold) # identifies first index
    if (is.na(idx.new)){
        break
    }   

    idx[idx.new] <- 1 # flags value above threshold
    d.y[idx.new+1] <- d.y[idx.new]+d.y[idx.new+1]
    d.x[idx.new+1] <- d.x[idx.new]+d.x[idx.new+1]
    d.x[idx.new] <- 0 # avoids that is above threshold
    dy_dx <- abs(d.y)/d.x
    } 
idx <- c(0,idx)
```

UPDATE: running it as a for-loop is significantly faster:

```
for (i in 1:length(dy_dx)){
    if (dy_dx[i] <= threshold){
      next
    }  else {

    idx[i] <- 1
    d.y[i+1]  <- d.y[i]+d.y[i+1]
    d.x[i+1] <- d.x[i]+d.x[i+1]
    dy_dx[i+1] <- abs(d.y[i+1])/(d.x[i+1])
    dy_dx[i] <- 0
    }
  }
```

Comment: It seems you have typos or I have a hard time to figure out whether you want `dx/dy` or `dy/dx`.

Comment: @Masoud thx, you're totally right - I fixed it.

Comment: Do you want the index positions for future subsetting? Do you want to keep the index positions? Discard the index positions?

Comment: @ChiPak I have no preference, as long as I end up with a vector that easily shows where the threshold was "violated". For example, in my MWE it's a vector with either 0 or 1 in case of violation; but a vector with only the indices is also fine.

Comment: why is `d.y` for row 5 `1` and not `-2`?

Comment: @Aramis7d, fixed :)

Comment: @Jonas I deleted my answer because it was no faster than your correct solution.